# DataGridViewLinkCell not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to achieve my first CRUD code in C# with SQL server. Every time you run the app and click on different cells, app crash

```
private void MLA_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewLinkCell cell = (DataGridViewLinkCell)MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (cell.Value.ToString() == "EDITAR")
    {
        AgregarMLA agregarMLA = new AgregarMLA();
        agregarMLA.LoadContact(new tablaMLA
        {

            URL_ID = int.Parse(MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()),
            URL_QUERY = (MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]).Value.ToString()
        });
        agregarMLA.ShowDialog(this);
    }
    else if (cell.Value.ToString() == "BORRAR")
    {

        BorrarMLA(int.Parse(MLA.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
        Populate();
    }
}
```

This function actually crash wherever you touch a cell does come from the sql server "select".

There's nothing else I could try because there is not much information about `DataGridViewLinkCell`.

Comment: As it is, your question is unlikely to attract an answer.  You would like us to help debug a crash in your code, but you don't show us how to reproduce the crash -- i.e., a [mcve].  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... **Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem***.  But with the code shown, we don't know how you are connecting to SQL server, getting data, or populating your grid.

Comment: Assuming your app throws an exception, simply [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74902798/edit) your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, full traceback and inner exception(s) if any would increase your chances of getting help.  Good luck!

Comment: Incidentally, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value), `DataGridViewCell.Value` has a default value of `null`, but your code doesn't check that before doing `cell.Value.ToString()`.  Possibly you want `cell.Value?.ToString()` instead.

Comment: Your code assumes every cell is a `DataGridViewLinkCell`.  Check first: `var cell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewLinkCell;` then `if (cell != null) {...}`

Comment: Thanks everyone for giving a hand. These are the first posts in stack and it's difficult for.me.to explain everything clearly. O don't have enough knowledge yet to include all the necessary code to reproduce crash. As far as I can get, error comes up wherever you click on another cell because code expect every cell to be link type. And that....I don't know how to change it. Thanks everyone again a merry Christmas